# google sheets clear some cells on page load

Tags: google-sheets, pageload

Is there any way to delete the values of some cells in google sheets when the user opens the sheet?
In fact I am using google sheets as a form and want the form to do some calculations. But when the user open the sheet I want to clear it. Is there any way to clear cells on page load?

Comment: You have you use Google Apps Script and an on open trigger. For best results use an installable trigger instead of a simple trigger. If you need further help start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets and https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

Answer (score 0):

From Extensions and then App script I add below code and saved it. Then it worked.

```
    function onOpen(e) {
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('your sheet name');
 sheet.getRange('G2:G18').clearContent();
}
```